# IDisposable, unmanaged fields, reference types and assignments

Tags: c#, unmanaged, idisposable, reference-type

If I have two instances of a class that implement `IDisposable` what happens to the unmanaged fields within the first class if it is assigned to the second.

For example, consider the following simplified class:

```
public unsafe class Image : IDisposable
{
    private float* pixelsBase;

    private GCHandle pixelsHandle;

    public Image(int width, int height)
    {
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;

        // Assign the pointer and pixels.
        this.Pixels = new float[width * height * 4];
        this.pixelsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(this.Pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        this.pixelsBase = (float*)this.pixelsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
    }

    public float[] Pixels {get; private set;}

    ~ImageBase()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Dispose of any managed resources here.
        }

        if (this.pixelsHandle.IsAllocated)
        {
            this.pixelsHandle.Free();
            this.pixelsBase = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What would happen to the `pixelsBase` field in an instance of the `Image` class was assigned to another one?

e.g

```
var firstImage = new Image(100, 200);
var secondImage; new Image(300, 300);

firstImage = secondImage;
```

Comment: You'll have two *references* to the same object, you are not copying the object.   Makes no difference to the GC, it only ever collects/finalizes an object when zero references are left.  You'll only have a problem if your code calls Dispose() and some other code elsewhere keeps using the object.  Ought to bomb with NRE somewhere, throw ObjectDisposedException to generate a better diagnostic.

Comment: I've expanded my example to make my question more clear. What happens to the unmanged resources if I have already assigned them. Do I end up with a memory leak?

Comment: Again nothing dramatic happens.  There is now no reference left to the first Image object you created.  The next garbage collection will destroy it.  You probably want to consult your favorite C# language book about the difference between references and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDisposable` has nothing to do with your question, since you're never calling it. The only thing that matters is the finalizer - while `IDisposable` and finalizers are related, the runtime doesn't care about `IDisposable` at all.

So, what do you get from using a finalizer? When your object is no longer referenced, its finalizer is put on the finalizer queue, and unless something process-killing happens, is executed after a while. In your case, this will release the `GCHandle` and allow the `Pixels` byte array to be collected as well.

Don't try to write C++ in C#, or understand C# in terms of C++. They look similar, but are very different - especially in memory management aspects. C# finalizers have very little in common with C++ destructors.

As a side-note, you want to avoid pinning managed objects for long - it prevents heap compaction from working properly, which means that unless your `Pixels` array is on the LOH, you're not going to get any memory below any pinned handle reclaimed when a collection occurs (*disclaimer*: this is an implementation detail of the current MS.NET runtime; contractually, .NET doesn't even *need* a garbage collector at all, and finalizers aren't guaranteed to ever run, much less finish).

Allocating unmanaged memory for your array might be a better idea if you're already dealing with pointers anyway. If you really want to use a managed array for your backing store, using `fixed` in a scope where you need the unmanaged pointer might be a better area than keeping the whole thing pinned for the lifetime of the whole object. In fact, your solution needs *at least* two collections to release the object's memory - the first one to eventually call the `GCHandle.Free`, the second to actually reclaim the memory that is now no longer pinned. Even if you manually call `Dispose`, you still need to wait for a collection to actually reclaim the memory.

Comment: Thanks for this. There's method to my approach but I'm always looking for improvements. I'm pinning the array so that I can use the pointer to provide fast access to the images pixels. This has to be fast within a loop so `fixed` won't do me any favours. If you want to see what this is for here's a [link to my ImageProcessor github repo](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor) .

Comment: @JamesSouth Hmm, yeah, but can't you use `fixed` *around* the loop? Have you done some performance profiling to see how the code really performs? If you really have to keep a live pointer to the data at all times, I would really suggest to keep the memory unmanaged - pinning memory undermines the goals of your library quite a lot (for one, it would kill you in any hosted environment). And it's not a very good idea to avoid bounds checking when not debugging - instead, find a way to make the check less frequent, but still always correct - again, "outside the loop" works great.

Comment: I did some benchmarking  while back and as I recall I got around a 20-25% improvement on fixed, unfortunately I cannot find my tests so will have to rewrite them. Theoretically I could move the fixed statement outside the loop but that would remove my ability to access pixels quickly using an indexer and make the API cumbersome. I have a discussion on perf [here](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/347) I would love to have your input on.

Comment: @JamesSouth I'd make the easiest way the safest, not necessarily the fastest. You can always add an option that's less safe - e.g. explicit locking/unlocking or alternatively, make a safe wrapper class for the image. An `Unsafe` method that takes a delegate as an argument to execute in the "unlocked" image might also be an interesting approach - you could even give the direct pointer for the really hardcore people. Having an entirely separate, purely safe and managed version of the library might also be useful - for example, for web hostings that don't give code full trust).

Comment: "explicit locking/unlocking" That is a GREAT idea thanks!